# Get constraint's id programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, constraints

Given the following xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/someTag"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:tag="someTag"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/someID"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/someID"
```

I would like to know how to get the id of

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf
```

(namely "someID") programatically.

Many thanks!

Comment: You want to set `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` programatically?

Comment: no, get it after it has been constructed manually inside the xml file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That attribute value is held in the `ImageView`'s `LayoutParams`, which are specifically [`ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams), in this case, since its parent is the `ConstraintLayout`.

`ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` has the [`bottomToTop`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.html#bottomToTop) field, which holds the ID of the `View` for that particular constraint.

Simply get the `ImageView`'s `LayoutParams`, cast them to `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`, and get your ID from the aforementioned field. For example:

```
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.someTag);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();
int bottomToTopId = lp.bottomToTop;
```

---

If, for some reason, you need the actual resource name for that ID, you can get it per usual with the `Resources#getResourceEntryName()` method. That is:

```
String viewIdName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(bottomToTopId); // returns "someID"
```