# change some parameters of an <include layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout, android-constraintlayout

I have an existing `<include layout` and need to change two parameters of this layout programmatically to set it in a TableLayout
one time have to perform:

```
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

and another time

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

this is the layout

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/search_results_cv"
    layout="@layout/addresses_card_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"// or wrap
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_location_cv"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"//one time want t call another time not
/>
```

I do not need a `ViewStub` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999601/how-can-i-programmatically-include-layout-in-android), because do not need to change the layout indicated in include, but the parameters inside include!

EDIT:

and this is the new include layout:

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/search_results_cv"
        layout="@layout/addresses_card_view"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_location_cv"
 />
```

Comment: I do not need to change the dimensions, how can I change layout height to wrap_content in dimens?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344196) should be of some help. In your case, after getting the `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`, you would set `lp.bottomToBottom` to the ID of whichever `View` is the new constraint. To wrap the height, you set `lp.height` to `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`. After you set your values, set the `LayoutParams` back on the `View` with `setLayoutParams(lp)`.

Comment: please see my edit Mike, does not work for some reasons I cannot debug

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: I mean I changed the  original post on the basis of your suggestion, and I showed you what I did

Comment: What were you saying about dpi? And how exactly does it not work?

Comment: was a typo, I meant "for" instead of "dpi", sorry I am on that since 10 hours

Comment: Also, why are you constraining the bottom of `search_results_cv` to its own bottom? That doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I am not good to use Kotlinx, I thought that is the way to call the <include layout being the `@id`

Comment: Nah, the `<include>` is fine. I mean this: `params.bottomToBottom=search_results_cv.bottom`. That needs to be set to a `View` ID, not a dimension or location.

Comment: do not get, I am asking get bottom so to emulate `layout_bottomToBottom' = parent

Comment: The `layout_bottomToBottom` attribute means "align my bottom to this other `View`'s bottom". You need to give it the ID of the `View` whose bottom you want the `include`'s bottom to align with; e.g., `R.id.otherView`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I might've misread that. If you mean you specifically want to set that to `parent` programmatically, then you could either use the `ConstraintLayout`'s `R.id` directly, or use `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID`. That is, `params.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID`.

Comment: you know a lot of things I cannot test now,  that I am without VPN, but gotta wait tomorrow morning, I think also that I have to pass as `val params` instead of the `include id`  the id global of `ConstraintLayout`, I edited the question again

Comment: You still haven't said exactly how it's not working. Does the `View` not go where it's supposed to? Is it the wrong dimensions? Does it just disappear? Does it crash? Does your computer catch fire?

Comment: ah ah, my brain catches fire, basically i tested before the views with the respective attributes and they were working, now I cannot test them because do not have access to the VPN, tomorrow morning at 8 Amsterdam time I will know. Thank you. I gave you three upvotes to some some post of you I liked. ( not that you need reputation:))

Comment: Well, let's hope it works. :-) Also, I really do appreciate the gesture, but please don't upvote unless you've used an answer, and it has helped you. Upvoting several in quick succession like that is called "serial voting", and it's rather frowned upon here. It might even be reversed anyway, since there's a script on the servers that looks for that. Again, though, I do appreciate the gesture. Good luck with this. Cheers!

Comment: I suspected that, but you helped me other times, and if  I grew before to find a job is because of people in SO as you. I will not do serial vote anymore:) Point taken

Comment: worked perfect, thank you Mike